# $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\sin\dfrac{k}{n^3}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, summation

Fịnd the value of

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n k \sin \frac k {n^3}  $$

Comment: I still don't have any ideas till now..

Comment: where would you start? what concepts would you use? what has your course been covering?

Comment: this kind of problem, I haven't met it before..

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k/n)$ converges to $\int_o^1 f(x) dx$ where $f$ is a real valued function on an interval.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle x-\frac{x^3}{6}\leq\sin x\leq x$

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k^2}{n^3}-\frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k^4}{n^9}\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\sin\dfrac{k}{n^3}\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k^2}{n^3}\enspace$ for sufficient large $n$

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k^4}{n^9}\in\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^4})$ which means that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k^4}{n^9}\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$

Therefore is $\enspace\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\sin\dfrac{k}{n^3}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k^2}{n^3}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}=\frac{1}{3}$ .